# Allow mapping of dynamic types using AutoMapper or similar?

Tags: c#, automapper, massive

I've started to use https://github.com/robconery/massive for a project, I wonder if there is any mapping tool that allows support for Dynamic to static type mapping?

I've used AutoMapper previously, does AutoMapper support this?

I am aware of the DynamicMap function from AutoMapper, however I believe this function is for running maps without creating the Map first. In my example below it does not work.

```
dynamic curUser = users.GetSingleUser(UserID);   
var retUser = Mapper.DynamicMap<UserModel>(curUser);
users.GetSingleUser(UserID); // returns a dynamic object
```

Comment: See [this q](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19529178/recursively-mapping-expandoobject) for a more complete answer.

Comment: @LiamB, "does AutoMapper support this?" - you mean automatic mapping between properties with equal/similar names? Or your mapping is more complex?

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev Sorry - I'm not sure, this question is 4 years old! :)

Comment: @LiamB, wow, indeed it is:)

Comment: I dont get it... As far as I see it the code above  is criminal. If I saw dynamics used in such a way I would have serious questions about said programmers abilities and the quality of the library used. I realize there might be some domain specific knowledge that isnt clear in the question but still.... C# != JavaScript. Why would any ORM return a dynamic? Yuck!

Comment: @MaximGershkovich This question and code is from 4 years ago - I havent used AutoMapper in a while now. However dynamics are extremely powerful and just because C# isnt JS doesn't mean the use of dynamics is bad.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

**[AutoMapper 4.2.0](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2016/01/28/automapper-4-2-0-released/) now supports [Dynamic/expando/dictionary mapping](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html)**

With this feature you can map to your expando objects to static types:

```
dynamic CurUser = _users.GetSingleUser(UserID);   
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { });
var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var retUser = mapper.Map<UserModel>(CurUser);
```

Old versions of AutoMapper do not support this (Massive internally uses `ExpandoObject` which doesn't provide  which properties it has), and you are right `Mapper.DynamicMap` is for mapping without creating mapping configuration.

Actually it's not hard to write yourself a mapper if you just want simple mapping:

```
public static class DynamicToStatic
{
    public static T ToStatic<T>(object expando)
    {
        var entity = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        //ExpandoObject implements dictionary
        var properties = expando as IDictionary<string, object>; 

        if (properties == null)
            return entity;

        foreach (var entry in properties)
        {
            var propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Key);
            if(propertyInfo!=null)
                propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, entry.Value, null);
        }
        return entity;
    }
}

dynamic CurUser = _users.GetSingleUser(UserID);   
var retUser = DynamicToStatic.ToStatic<UserModel>(CurUser);
```

Comment: I have been struggling with this for hours this afternoon +1. Thanks

Comment: @nemesv "[...]ExpandoObject which doesn't provide which properties it has)[...]" <--- ExpandoObject implements `IDictionary<string, object>` so you can cast to this interface and use `ContainsKey`.

Comment: Just in case somebody has issues finding properties. GetProperty(...) is case sensitive by default. Use the following flags to make it not case sensitive  .GetProperty(entry.Key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

Comment: Using empty config doesn't work with collections.

Answer (score 17):

Try **Slapper.AutoMapper** https://github.com/randyburden/Slapper.AutoMapper

> Slapper.AutoMapper maps dynamic data to static types

It works for both `dynamic` and `Dictionary<A, B>` which is awesome.

Here's an example (taken from the URL above) showing how easily it works with Dictionary:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id;
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
}

[Test]
public void CanMapMatchingFieldNamesWithEase()
{
    // Arrange
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>
                            {
                                { "Id", 1 },
                                { "FirstName", "Clark" },
                                { "LastName", "Kent" }
                            };

    // Act
    var person = Slapper.AutoMapper.Map<Person>( dictionary );

    // Assert
    Assert.NotNull( person );
    Assert.That( person.Id == 1 );
    Assert.That( person.FirstName == "Clark" );
    Assert.That( person.LastName == "Kent" );
}
```

Comment: This works with deep hierarchies, but aah.. the `_` convention is a bummer.. :(

Comment: nooooooooo, I didn't mean the name of your method. I meant, this is one library that will work with deep hierarchies in class structure (complex class structure unlike the example in your answer) unlike the accepted answer, but it requires a certain "naming convention" to work. See the link for an example.

Comment: Apologies I should have paid more attention! :) I agree it would be nicer if the sub-dynamic-types were properties of the parent so you get Foo.Bar.Baz instead of Foo_Bar_Baz...

Comment: @nawfal The "_" convention can be customised, e.g.  `Slapper.AutoMapper.Configuration.IdentifierConventions.Add( type => type.Name + "_Id" );`, see http://randyburden.com/Slapper.AutoMapper/.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming framework you use returns `ExpandoObject` you can achieve some sort of dynamic mapping using AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ExpandoObject, UserModel>()
    .ForAllMembers((options) => options.ResolveUsing((resolution) =>
        {
            var dictionary =  (IDictionary<string, object>) resolution.Context.SourceValue;
            return dictionary[resolution.Context.MemberName];
        }));
...
dynamic CurUser = _users.GetSingleUser(UserID);   
var retUser = Mapper.Map<UserModel>(CurUser);
```

You can create any sort of complex mapping using `ConstructUsing` methods..

Answer (score 0):

Single object:

```
Mapper.Map<Product>(dynamicProduct);
```

List:

```
Mapper.Map<List<Product>>(dynamicListOfProducts);
```

Example (line 71): https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/DynamicMapping.cs