# Automapper map from System.Dynamic.DynamicObject

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamic, automapper

I'm having a really difficult time mapping from a DynamicObject using Automapper -- the properties on my destination type always end up null even though they do map to a property of the same name.  I assume this has to do with reflection issues on DynamicObjects...  Is Automapper able to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AutoMapper (Or Similar) - Allow Mapping of Dynamic types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778216/automapper-or-similar-allow-mapping-of-dynamic-types)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar question to [Allow mapping of dynamic types using AutoMapper or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778216/automapper-or-similar-allow-mapping-of-dynamic-types)

In summary AutoMapper does not support this. It's easy to write your own mapper to do this using reflection though. The accepted answer to [Allow mapping of dynamic types using AutoMapper or similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778216/automapper-or-similar-allow-mapping-of-dynamic-types) has an example of this.