# Mapping use Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, anonymous-types

How to map List of anonymous to List of T using AutoMapper?

For example:

```
class Test{
  public string a1{get;set]}
  public string a2{get;set;}
}

//....Entity Framework 4.3.1
var t=from z in db select {z.a1,z.a2};

var tmp=AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<List<Test>>(t);
```

But tmp always is empty

How to fix it?

Comment: does it work without dynamicmapping? something like Mapper.CreateMap<db.test, Test>();
var tmp = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<db.test>, List<Test>>(t);

Comment: var t is IQueriable of anonymous class and cannot use with this form (db.test)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to call t.ToList() to execute the query first

```
var tmp=AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<List<Test>>(t.ToList());
```

Comment: daft question probably, but does calling t.ToList() return the expected number of items?

Comment: see gist https://gist.github.com/2491229. It doesn't use Automapper but uses LINQ to achieve the same result. Hope this helps

Comment: It's good but AutoMapper allows create calculated field and custom casting and...

Comment: Automapper has an open issue - https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/148 related to dynamic mapping for collection and arrays.  I have updated the gist - https://gist.github.com/2491229 with an alternate use of AutoMapper dynamic mapping. Hope you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

how about you change

```
var t=from z in db select new Test
                          {
                             a1 = z.a1,
                             a2 = z.a2
                           }
```

**EDIT** 
to allow mapping to dynamic types , you can refer to [existing post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778216/automapper-or-similar-allow-mapping-of-dynamic-types)

Comment: Thanks. with this mode LINQ AutoMapper not needed but if LINQ query return extra fields than Test class, does't work. Is there any other Solution؟

Comment: @user1356462 : have you found out other the solution ?