# Properly convert dynamic to static

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a `dynamic` object in C# that I'd like to convert to a static object. I wrote a function that takes the dynamic type and returns the static type, but it actually returns `dynamic`, ignoring the specified return type. (This is standard behavior, as I've now discovered.) AutoMapper doesn't handle `dynamic` types. How can I properly convert `dynamic` to static?

Comment: My post specifically says "AutoMapper doesn't handle `dynamic` types", so yes, I've seen it. Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7778398/1672458) outdated?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778216/automapper-or-similar-allow-mapping-of-dynamic-types

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: I have no idea how that answer works, but I guess it is a duplicate. My apologies.

Comment: @DanielA.White Actually, that code doesn't work--it returns `dynamic`. Do my `dynamic`s all need to be `expando` for that to work properly?

Comment: @Vaindil adding an explicit cast should work: `(T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dynobj))`

Answer (score 3):

Using some serializers can be a solution. Suppose you form a dynamic object like

```
dynamic d = new ExpandoObject();
d.a = 1;
d.b = new ExpandoObject();
d.b.c = "222";
```

and you want to cast this to `A`

```
public class A
{
    public int a { set; get; }
    public B   b { set; get; }
}

public class B
{
    public string c { set; get; }
}
```

You can use, for example, [Json.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json), to do this serialization/deserialization

```
A a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got the type, you can instanciate a new object, then copy the state of your dynamic object into this object with the [FormatterServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices(v=vs.110).aspx) class:

```
var staticObject = Activator.CreateInstance(yourType);
MemberInfo[] members = FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(yourType);
FormatterServices.PopulateObjectMembers(staticObject, members, 
  FormatterServices.GetObjectData(dynObject, members));
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm confused... I thought that .NET should already do this for you. Here's some test code and it fits with my expectations:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        dynamic anythingGoes = 1;
        var convertedToInt = ConvertToType<int>(anythingGoes);

        // expectation: should output Int32. and it does....
        Console.WriteLine(convertedToInt.GetType().Name);


        anythingGoes = "ribbit";
        var convertedToString = ConvertToType<string>(anythingGoes);

        // expectation: should output String. and it does also...
        Console.WriteLine(convertedToString.GetType().Name);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    // just a small method to cast the dynamic to whatever i want
    // ...only for this test. not guaranteed to be crash safe. in fact, don't assume!
    static T ConvertToType<T>(dynamic obj)
    {
        T result = obj;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: In Visual Studio put your cursor over `var`.  You'll see that it is typed as `dynamic`.  The runtime type of convertedString will always be `string` but the compile time type will be `dynamic` which is the issue here.

Comment: @EZI: did you? I did, hence the inline comments in my code sample.