# Return EF Object as normal array in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

After populating an EF Object (`users` for instance) with data and return it from WebAPI, i get it in json format as follows:

```
[
    {"username":"lakshman553","email":"abc@xyz.com","phone":1234567},
    {"username":"lakshman323","email":"pqr@xyz.com","phone":"122267"},
]
```

Since i use the webapi completely for internal purposes, i would rather like the data as follows:

```
[
     ["lakshman553","abc@xyz.com",1234567], 
     ["lakshman323","pqr@xyz.com",1222267]
]
```

i can decrease the payload drastically by doing this way when the data is high, which typically is the case.

How to achieve this in C#. Iterating through the `users` object and assigning it to a sized array of row and column count is one approach i know, but is there a straight method for doing this?

thanks.

Comment: If you care about amount of data being transferred, consider more efficient serialization approach (BSON, protobuf) instead of writing custom mapping code.

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this transformation using LINQ extension methods as follows:

```
// Project each list item into an array of item property values
var array4all = list.Select
(
    item => item.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                          .Select(property => property.GetValue(item))
                          .ToArray()
).ToArray();
```

BTW, IMHO I'm concerned about this sentence:

> Since i use the webapi completely for internal purposes [...]

I believe you're trying to simplify the problem creating a new problem. In terms of coding, readability and maintainaibility I find that you're making things tougher.

Maybe something like obfuscating property names to `a`, `b`, `c`.... and you might use [*AutoMapper*](http://automapper.org/) to map a [`dynamic` DTO](http://designpattern.ninja/architectural/c%23/n-layer/strong-typing/dynamic-typing/duck-typing/dynamic-tuple-dto) [to your actual model/DTO with full property names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778216/allow-mapping-of-dynamic-types-using-automapper-or-similar). Something like:

```
{ "a": "hello world", "b": 20 } => { "text": "hello world", "number": 20 }
```

Or you can take a look at [MsgPack](http://msgpack.org/index.html), [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/)...

Answer (score 1):

If you gzip your server’s response (which you should), then those repeated property names don’t really matter much. On the other hand, having the properties as properties makes handling the data *a lot* easier for both the provider and the consumer.

You say you use it only for internal purposes, but you’d still need to build a custom parsing mechanism for this when you consume that data. And to do that, you need to have a consistent way of doing so, so you need additional contracts that define e.g. the order of the properties, and—when parsing into C#—also its types etc.

That’s a lot overhead just to reduce the bandwidth, which as I said above doesn’t really matter much once you gzip the data.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
var users = new[] 
{
    new { username = "lakshman553", email = "abc@xyz.com", phone = "1234567" },
    new { username = "lakshman323", email = "pqr@xyz.com", phone = "122267" }
};

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JArray.FromObject(users).Select(_ => _.Values()));
```

**Output**:

```
[["lakshman553","abc@xyz.com","1234567"],["lakshman323","pqr@xyz.com","122267"]]
```